# Unable to pull in custom product attribute in shortcode

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I have this code working directly on a page.  But when I try to add it to a shortcode in the function.php it is not working. It will not pull in the author (or the date).

```php
<?php 
//LIST ALL DOCUMENTS
add_shortcode('listDocs','listDocs');
function listDocs(){
    $params = array(
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
        'posts_per_page' => 25, 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'product_cat' => 'documents'
      );
      $product = wc_get_product();
      $author = $product->get_attribute('document-type');
      $date = get_the_date('F Y', $product->get_id());
  $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
      while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
           $wc_query->the_post(); 
           $output .= '<h3 style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 0px;"> <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>
           <p>' . get_field('document_type') . ' / ' .  $author . ' / ' . $date . '</p><hr>';
        }

        return $output; 


}
    ?>
```

Comment: Where are you using the shortcode?

Comment: I am putting it on a page that will list specific products - in my case documents.

Comment: You code uses `wc_get_product()`. If you’re using it on a page, _which_ product?

Comment: Thank you!  I got it working by adding:
$product_id = get_the_ID();
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs it, here was my final code:

```
<?php 
//LIST ALL DOCUMENTS
add_shortcode('listDocs','listDocs');
function listDocs(){
    $params = array(
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
        'posts_per_page' => 25, 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'product_cat' => 'documents'
      );
  $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
      while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
           $wc_query->the_post(); 
           $product_id = get_the_ID();
           $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
           $author = $product->get_attribute('written-by');
           $date = get_the_date('F Y', $product_id);
           $output .= '<h3 style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 0px;"> <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>
           <p>' . get_field('document_type') . ' / ' .  $author . ' / ' . $date . '</p><hr>';
        }

        return $output; 


}
    ?>
```